# Plotting 2 ACFs ggplot2 - Show Minimum Value Colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to plot 2 ACFs in R using ggplot. I use geom_segment() and it works fine, but a slight annoying detail is that depending on the order I declare geom_segment, the plot will overlay the smallest ACFs if I declare these before the largest value. This would not be the problem if one ACF had always a larger value (case in which I would geom_segment that before). I know it sounds confusing, so here is a working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(plyr)

set.seed(123)
data1 <- arima.sim(n = 10000, model = list(ar = 0.4,ma=0.4))
data2 <- arima.sim(n = 10000, model = list(ma = c(0.9,0.3)))

acf1 <- acf(data1, plot = FALSE,lag.max=15)
acf1DF <- with(acf1, data.frame(lag, acf))
acf1DF$lag <- as.integer(acf1DF$lag)
acf2 <- acf(data2, plot = FALSE,lag.max=15)
acf2DF <- with(acf2, data.frame(lag, acf))
acf2DF$lag <- as.integer(acf2DF$lag)

q <- ggplot(data = acf1DF, mapping = aes(x = lag, y = acf)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(xend = lag, yend = 0,color="red")) +
  geom_segment(data=acf2DF,mapping = aes(x=lag,y=acf,xend = lag, yend = 0),
    inherit.aes=FALSE,show.legend=FALSE)
q
```

Note that I cannot see the smallest value for the first lag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be a solution for you to create a barplot instead? The issue that segments overlapping makes your plot less understandable, might point to using a different visualization as a solution. Here is a barplot:

First, we combine the data as generally in ggplot, when you call a `geom` multiple times, you're not doing things right.

```
acf1DF$group <- 1
acf2DF$group <- 2

dat <- rbind(acf1DF,acf2DF)
```

Then we can make a barplot:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor(lag), y=acf,fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.3,stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]
Or, if we really want segments and not bars (for instance because we want a continuous x-axis, or like the look of lines as a legend), we can add a slight offset to lag in group 2 before plotting

```
dat$lag_offset <- dat$lag + as.numeric(dat$group==2) * 0.1
```

And then plot segments:

```
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=lag_offset, xend=lag_offset, y=0,yend=acf, color=factor(group))) +
  geom_segment() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(`1`="black",`2`="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks; I am starting to get the gist of ggplot data arrangement.

Comment: You're welcome! I know it can be very helpful to see your data int the right format once. And knowing how to wrangle data into a shape ggplot wants it (long, with all information for a datapoint on a line) will make your ggplot-life easier.